# How to find all combinations between string vectors in python

Tags: python, string, character, sequence, outer-join

Consider the two following string sequences:

```
Salutation = ["Hello", "Hi"]
Names = ["Alice", "Matt", "Franck", "Julia"]
```

I am looking for clean way to merge those sequences into

```
["Hello_Alice", "Hi_Alice", "Hello_Matt", "Hi_Matt", "Hello_Franck", "Hi_Franck", "Hello_Julia", "Hi_Julia"]
```

or with whatever separator.

The equivalent in R would be:

```
c(outer(Salutations, Names, paste, sep="_"))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`itertools.product` is what you're looking for

```
import itertools
output = ['_'.join(i) for i in itertools.product(Salutation, Names)]
#or whatever separator you want
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use nested for loops like this:

```
l = []
for s in Salutation:
    for n in Names:
        l.append(s + "_" + n)
```